# Ajax load the category custom product collection on custom phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I have a phtml file which displays all subcategory with its product.I want to load the products of particular category section using ajax when user select a radio button.Give me some solution.
sample code customphtml file.

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    <li class="grid12-3">
        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" class="clearfix">
            <?php if($thumbFile = $category->getThumbnail()): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $thumbFile;?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
            <?php endif;?>
            <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span></a>
    </li>

    <!-- Load (3) Products from within each subcategory  -->
    <?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        ->load();
    ?>
    <?php $toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton(‘catalog/product_list’)->getToolbarBlock();
    $toolbar->setCollection($products);
    $pager = $layout->createBlock(‘page/html_pager’);
    $toolbar->setChild(‘product_list_toolbar_pager’, $pager);
    echo $toolbar->toHtml();
    ?>
    <?php  if($toolbar-<getCurrentMode()!=grid)
    {
    ?>
    <!-- Display Each product's detailed info  -->
    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <li>
        <?php // Product Image ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
        <?php // Product description ?>
       <input class="my-activity"
                     type="radio"
                     id="product<?php echo $_product->getId();?>"
                     name="<?php echo str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($catname['name'])) ?>"
                     value="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"  <?php echo $checked; ?> onclick="saveselectedproduct(<?php echo $catname['catid']; ?>)">   <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($product->getName(), null, true); ?>
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($product, $product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ; ?>
```

```
      function saveselectedproduct(catid)
      {

                 url2="<?php echo      $this->getUrl('compatibility/compatiblelist/getcollection'); ?>";
              $j.ajax({
                        url:url2,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data:{catid:catid},
                        success: function(data) {
                               alert($data);
                        }});
            }
  </script>
```

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: i had called a controller function and got the collection in ajax function but want to display the collection in that category how the collection for that category be updated

Comment: kindly add you phtml and your controller code too

Comment: @Qaisar Satti check my updated question in which my code is added

Comment: add this js function `saveselectedproduct`

Comment: @QaisarSatti I have added script

Comment: You have written Code Procedure way, that is not recommended , please write it magento way. Create block and with on block call model and call block function in phtml.

Comment: can you add controller method too and tell me you want to show the product base on radio selection?

Comment: @QaisarSatti  data['productcoll']  consists of product collection just want to display that collection in the catid send in saveselectedproduct(catid) function

Comment: i added the solution follow that.

Comment: @QaisarSatti  thanks for answer but i m not displaying single category product .I am  displaying all  subcategory with its product collection in phtml

Comment: add that code too..

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getcollectionAction()
{  // you can load the collection with category id
    $catid=$this->getRequest()->getPist('catid');
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);

 $categories = $category->getAllChildren(true);
 $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
 $products->addCategoriesFilter($categories);

  //if you want to display the product too
 $this->loadLayout(); 
 Mage::register('category_collection', $products);
 $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');
    $block->setTemplate('test/test.phtml');
    // this will json response
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($block->toHtml())); 

}
```

test.phtml

```
$collection=Mage::registry('category_collection');
 foreach($collection as $product)
 {
   // do you code here
 }
```